# How to untangle a graph?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, graph-theory

I have an API that sends me the information of the following source graph (You may assume A, B & C to have a common parent)

[image: Constructed graph]

as the following JSON (ignore the string and number values, purely representational; order of the keys is non-deterministic)

```
{
    "f": {
        "childOf": {
            "d": "own"
        },
        "data": 6
    },
    "d": {
        "childOf": {
            "b": "foster"
        },
        "data": 4
    },
    "a": {
        "data": 1
    },
    "h": {
        "childOf": {
            "f": "step"
        },
        "data": 8
    },
    "g": {
        "childOf": {
            "e": "foster",
            "a": "own"
        },
        "data": 7
    },
    "c": {
        "data": 3
    },
    "e": {
        "childOf": {
            "c": "step"
        },
        "data": 5
    },
    "b": {
        "data": 2
    },
    "i": {
        "childOf": {
            "a": "step"
        },
        "data": 9
    }
}
```

For building the graphical representation from the json, I wrote a function that gives me the levels at which each node occurs, based on the data provided by the childOf property. The result is something like

```
[
    ["a", "b", "c"],
    ["i", "d", "e"],
    ["g", "f"],
    ["h"]
]
```

which, while vertically correct, has no consideration for the left to right order of the nodes in the source representation. This sometimes leads to the following (tangled) graph (see red and blue edges)

[image: Tangled Reconstruction]

How would I obtain an untangled graph from information in the above JSON format? (knowing that the source representation is always untangled, and hence an untangled solution must exist)

Idea 1: An idea I have for the implementation is DFS with priority. For example, if the DFS starts at A and reaches G, it should prioritise E and subsequently C when it chooses siblings to dive for the next branch.

Comment: Are there cycles or is it always a DAG?

Comment: @Primusa Always a DAG

Comment: follow up, it seems like each node is only directed into at most one other? So is it always a tree too? (or forest)

Comment: @Primusa No. A node can have multiple parents (see G). A node may have multiple children as well. To add a child i to a, simple add the key "i" with value `{"childOf":{"a":"own"}}` to the json. However, even with multiple parents and children, it is guaranteed that the source representation is always untangled, and hence an untangled solution must exist.

Comment: Untangling a graph is NP-hard problem. Start your studies at [Xavier Goaoc article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0709.0170.pdf)

Comment: Is it possible to have multiple paths between 2 nodes? This is not the case in the drawn example (if we ignore the statement about A B C having a common parent), but maybe that was just coincidence?

Comment: Yes there may be multiple paths between 2 nodes. Assume example as A having children B & C, and both having common child D. Thus there are 2 paths ABD and ACD from A to D.

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas forgive me if I'm incorrect, I did not read the entire article. However, the paper seems to be talking about undirected graphs which may have cycles. My use case seems simpler in comparison.

Comment: An idea I have for the implementation is DFS with priority. For example, if the DFS starts at A and reaches G, it should prioritise E and subsequently C when it chooses siblings to dive for the next branch.

Comment: I'm definitely no expert, but it sounds like you might be confusing tangled graphs with non-[planar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph) graphs. Only a few classes of graphs can be planar.

Comment: @KaustubhBadrike In directed graph, there will be smaller number of vertex permutations needed to check, cause you need to analyze just vertex translation to the right or to the left. Still finding a minimum number of vertex translations needed to make graph untangled - `min(d(δ, δ′))` is not a trivial task. It's much like brute-force solution.

Comment: @user560822 I might. I don't really know what to call a graph with non-intersecting edges.